# sed - remove period at end of line

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to remove periods that are at the end of line in a text file. Some lines have periods at the end, some don't:

```
$cat textfile
sometexthere.123..22.no_period
moretext_with_period.  **<-- remove this period**
no_period_here_either
period.   **<-- remove this period**
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
sed 's/\.$//g' textfile > textfile2
```

(GNU sed version 4.2.1)

Thanks

Comment: Might be enlightening to see the output of `$ cat -vet textfile`.

Comment: Why do you use the `g` modifier?

Answer (score 8):

This is a shot in the dark, but I had this problem before when I tried to mix Windows files with Linux files. Windows adds an extra `\r` on every line break (in addition to the standard `\n`)Have you tried using dos2unix?

```
[user@localhost ~]$ cat testfile
abc
def.
[user@localhost ~]$ sed 's/\.$//g' testfile
abc
def.
[user@localhost ~]$ dos2unix testfile
dos2unix: converting file testfile to UNIX format ...
[user@localhost ~]$ sed 's/\.$//g' testfile
abc
def
[user@localhost ~]$
```

**Example this -**

```
[user@localhost ~]$ cat temp.txt 
this is a text created on windows
I will send this to unix
and do cat command.

[user@localhost ~]$ cat -v temp.txt 
this is a text created on windows^M
I will send this to unix^M
and do cat command.
```

Comment: This seems to work. dos2unix seems to do "something" with the file so that the command sed 's/\.$//g' now works... What has dos2unix actally done?
My text file is a column from a very large csv file in case people wonder.

Comment: At the end of every line on a Linux file is `\n`, but on the end of every line on a Windows file is `\r\n`. Your regex wasn't matching because the period was not directly next to the `\n` (the `\r` was in the way).

Comment: I have added an example in this solution. Once it is reviewed you should be able to see it. If you notice such anomalies, a good way of inspecting is to do a `cat -v filename`. This would show all non-printing characters so that they are visible.

Comment: @Jaypal: `cat -A filename`, if you have a version of `cat` that supports it, is even better.  In addition to showing non-printable characters in printable format, it replaces tabs with `^I` and adds `$` to the end of each line.

Comment: `cat -vet filename` where `-A` option is not available. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you need a single `sed` command to do this, without using `dos2unix`, which changes the original file in place, you can do something like this (may require GNU sed)

```
sed -E 's/\.(^M?)/\1/' testfile
```

Where you type `^M` on the command line as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

This will remove a '.', optionally followed by a Carriage-return character, and replaces the CR if it was present in the original.

Answer (score 1):

### sed 's/period[.| ]*$//g' ts.txt > ts1.txt

input file:
sometexthere.123..22.no_period
moretext_with_period.
no_period_here_either
period.

output file:
sometexthere.123..22.no_
moretext_with_
no_period_here_either

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/\.$//'
```

This should also work for removing the last period.

Comment: I believe you have a redundant '\'
sed -r 's/\.$//' worked for me.