# Remove period character from beginning of line with sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, replace

hope somebody can help me. I am trying to remove a `.` period character from the beginning of a line in a large list.

Example input list

```
.doubleclick.com
.doubleclick.net
0------------0-------------0.0n-line.info
0----0.0----0.1596.hk
```

If have tried this sed pipe `sed 's/^.//' < input.txt > output.txt`

But this gives me

```
doubleclick.com
doubleclick.net
------------0-------------0.0n-line.info
```

I have tried various other suggestions I found but nothing works as it is stripping the first period but also `0.` from a domain name like `0------------0-------------0.0n-line.info`

I need to only strip the first dot and nothing else.

Comment: See: [sed - remove period at end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8317447/3776858)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` is a meta-character that matches any character, so you need to escape it to match it literally

```
$ # can also use: sed 's/^[.]//' ip.txt
$ sed 's/^\.//' ip.txt
doubleclick.com
doubleclick.net
0------------0-------------0.0n-line.info
0----0.0----0.1596.hk
```

See also [sed manual - Overview of basic regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax)

Answer (score 3):

Since tagged [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk 'sub(/^\./,"")+1' infile
```

**Explanation:**

- `sub(..)` returns true, if substitution was made, and hence record will be printed, if not below `+1` takes care of printing.
- `+1` at the end does default operation that is print current/record/row, `print $0`. To know how awk works try, `awk '1' infile`, which will print all records/lines, whereas `awk '0' infile` prints nothing. Any number other than zero is *true*, which triggers the default behaviour.

Test Results:

```
$ cat f2
.doubleclick.com
.doubleclick.net
0------------0-------------0.0n-line.info
0----0.0----0.1596.hk

$ awk 'sub(/^\./,"")+1' f2
doubleclick.com
doubleclick.net
0------------0-------------0.0n-line.info
0----0.0----0.1596.hk
```

Comment: Thanks @TomFenech the sed works 100% for me. I do, as per one of me previous questions admit I need to learn more about awk so I certainly will not discard your answer and will test it too. I love learning new ways of doing things so truly appreciate your time to answer me.

Answer (score -2):

```
awk '/^.d/sub(/./,"")' file

doubleclick.com
doubleclick.net
------------0-------------0.0n-line.info
----0.0----0.1596.hk
```

Comment: sorry, but note that `echo "Xydoubleclick.com" | awk '/.d/sub(/./,"")'` also returns "doubleclick.com", would means it is NOT matching a leading `.` char, but is matching as a reg-exp `.="any-char"`.

Comment: As far as I understand it gives "ydoubleclick.com" which is quite another thing.

Comment: Arg, yes, editing error, but try `echo "Xdoubleclick.com" | awk '/.d/sub(/./,"")'`. You'll get `doubleclick.com`. In either case, the `sub(/./,"")` is still interpreting `.` as "any-char". Good luck to all.